# Message Queue(MSMQ) does not throw exception when message is not received on the other end

Tags: msmq

Let's say I try to send to an authenticated transactional queue,

by calling msg.send(object,MessageQueueTransactionType.Single), **message does not receive in transactional queue, no exception thrown**.

What I want to accomplish is after sending, **if message fail to send, perform some function and abort transaction**, yet it doesn't throw exception, so I am unable to process it.

I am sending object from Web Application in local to local message queue.

My code is as follows in my web application:

```cs
MessageQueueTransaction mqTran=new MessageQueueTransaction();

try
{
  using(System.Messaging.Message msg=new System.Messaging.Message(){
  mqTran.Begin();

  MessageQueue adminQ = new MessageQueue(AdminQueuePath);
  MessageQueue msgQ = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
  msgQ.DefaultPropertiesToSend.Recoverable = true;

  msg.body = object;
  msg.Recoverable=true;
  msg.Label="Object";
  msg.TimeToReachQueue=new TimeSpan(0,0,30);
  msg.AcknowledgeType=AcknowledgeTypes.FullReachQueue;
  msg.ResponseQueue=adminQ;
  msg.AdministrationQueue=adminQ;
  msgQ1.Send(msg,MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
  mqTran.Commit();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  mqTran.Abort();
  //Do some processing if fail to send
}
```

Comment: "I am sending object from Web Application in local to local message queue." Does that mean the sending app and the receiving queue are on the same machine?

Comment: yes they are on the same machine, so should I implement MSMQ or generate my self-generated queue class?

Comment: MSMQ is fine. It's just the underlying process is very different. No outgoing queues, for example. A Send() will put the message into the destination queue directly instead of into an intermediary outgoing queue for onward delivery. If you fail to send, you will get an exception back immediately. Your try/catch should be around the send().

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to throw an exception for failure to deliver, only for failure to place on the queue. One of the points of message queueing is that the messages are durable so that you can take appropriate measures if delivery fails. This means you need to program another process to read the dead letter queue. The image below is taken from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms699870%28v=vs.85%29).

[image]

Because the entire process is asynchronous, your code flow is not going to be exception-driven the way your code block would like. Your transaction is simply the "sending transaction" in this workflow.

Recommendation: Check your message queue to find the messages, either in the outgoing queue or the transactional dead-letter queue.

Comment: so how should i implement this in my code? I can't really check the dead-letter queue belongs to which application assuming more than 1 application is sending to the same message queue at the same time.

Comment: let's say after send I add one more statement: msgQ1.PeekById(msg.Id);

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, my "Recommendation" was referring to troubleshooting, as opposed to a coding solution. For that, you'd probably want to create a separate Windows service that peeks at the queue periodically and sends an alert message if it gets too far backed up.

Comment: so if msg fail to send to dest, it will definitely be in dead msg queue and not be lost?what i wish to know there is a guarantee for no lost of data

Comment: No, failure to send to local queue means the message cannot be created in the first place and you get an exception. Dead letter queues are for messages that can be created but fail on eventual delivery.

Comment: @user1663380 Make sure you set `Durable` to true. This will keep the messages from being lost. They'll either remain in the outgoing queue, or end up on the dead letter queue, where they can be recovered.

Comment: let's say you send to an authenticated queue, but your message does not appear there, where does it go? dead letter queues?

Comment: any idea how to set authentication credentials for authenticated MSMQ in code behind when sending?

Comment: You don't set the credentials in code. You set them on the machine, but giving your IIS app pool identity (if you're doing this in a web app) permissions to the particular queue.

Comment: also, is it possible to write and read from MSMQ at the same time, will it cause any problems?